# Узнать сумму, не используя библиотеку <math.h>

Tags: c, циклы, математика

Выводит ( Suma = -nan ).
Пожалуйста, объясните что как и почему.
[image: Сумма]

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int  N,n=1;
    float a = 0, sum=0,an,E=1;
    int znam = 1; 
    double ches = 1, mnoz = 1,pow;

    printf_s("Input N ="); scanf_s("%d", &N);
    printf_s("\n Input a ="); scanf_s("%f", &a);
    pow = -1;
    for (n = 0;n <= N;n++) {
        pow = pow * (n + 1);
    }
    an = a;
    for (n = 0;n <= N;n++) {
        an = an * a;
    }
    for (int n = 0;n <= N;++n) {
        E *= pow * (an / n);
            sum += E;
    }
    printf_s("Suma = %f", sum);
}
```

Comment: Вы делите на ноль в первой итерации последнего цикла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чему равно `(an / n)` при `n = 0`?

---

```
E = -1.0;
for (int n = 1; n <= N; ++n) {
    E = E * (-1) * a;
    sum += E / n;
}
```